# django crispy inline formset as table - delete column table header is missing

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

by defining an inline table for a django crispy form I noticed, that the description of the delete column is missing. Moreover the html code is not correct because the an  element is missing.

My code:

```
TeamPlayerFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Team, Teamplayer,  extra=7, fields=("user", "position","shirt_number","team_joined",))
formTeamPlayer =TeamPlayerFormSet()
```

The only way of fixing i have found was by changing Line 23 of the template (bootstrap/table_inline_formset.html).

from:

```
{% if field.label and not field|is_checkbox and not field.is_hidden %}
```

to

```
{% if field.label and not field.is_hidden %}
```

do you know whats the reason why this was included there?

Answer (score 0):

A solution was merged in dev a few times ago, but never added in stable/production branch.

https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/commit/78a792dadba8ffed08b756646afc766f6e64d805

If it's important for your project to have this label, a solution would be to fork django-crispy-forms and add this fix in your forked version.